# Regex: Search for a repeating group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string that contains this group :

```
"|__|" or "|__|__|__|..."
```

With my pattern `([\|__|]{3,})` It will get the desired result but it captures different strings too, like this *"Name ***_*____**"*

**Q:** How can I capture only this kind of repeating group `"|__|__|..."` for this string ?

```
"Name _________ Age___ Postal Code|__|__|__|__|__|"
```

Comment: I think that in my pattern the "|" vertical bar is considered an OR operator.

Comment: `[\|__|]` means that it will capture any of these characters: `\ `, `|` or `_`. So you actually want `(\|__\|)`

Comment: but why do you need to capture those empty fields..what are you trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[\|__|]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), matching *one*  character (`|` or `_`; the `\` is not necessary here and will be ignored).

You need a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
(\|__){3,}\|
```

(although, strictly, a non-capturing group would be the most sensible (but slightly less readable) construct here:)

```
(?:\|__){3,}\|
```

Comment: Wouldn't `[\|__|]` also match `\ `?

Comment: @Nolonar: I think the unnecessary backslash is ignored. It would be matched if there were two backslashes (and an verbatim string was being used).

Comment: "?" is for Ungreedy, but for what is the ":" used here ?

Comment: @Misi: No, the `?` can have many different meanings. After an opening parenthesis, together with `:` it makes the group non-capturing. Read the tutorial I linked to for a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: Normally, if you put something in brackets then it is "back-referenced" - i.e. saved as a variable. But by writing (:?...), the stuff in brackets is NOT saved as a variable. (A "non-capturing" group.) In other words, this won't really change how the regex actually works at all; it just makes the code more efficient. (You're not saving a variable for no reason!)